# Effecient way for finding multiple values of one dataframe in another

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (RES1):

```
   "sequence" "support"
"1" "<{OV50}>"   0.286
"2" "<{OV148}>"  0.121
"3" "<{OV46},{OV197}>" 0.065
"4" "<{OV198},{OV199}, {OV205}>" 0.065
```

And additional dataframe (SRC2):

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"
```

I would like to get the following output dataframe (OUT3):

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1       0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"     0
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"    1       0.5
```

For Each row in SRC2 the "Exist" column in OUT3 will be '0' if there is no value at all in RES1. For instance, OV11 doesn't appear in RES1 at all so its value is 0.
At the last value of sequenceID - the amount of '1' values is divided by the number of the same sequenceID and is added to "Co" column. In line 3 the there were 3 lines of sequenceID = 42207993 number of '1' are 2 so 2/3 = 0.67.
I would like to find the most efficient way to do it because each of the dataframes is very big dataframe.

In addition, in case of lines that contains 2 sequences or more. I would like to find them in their right order it means if OV46 appears before OV197 for the same sequenceID (57237976) I would like to indicate 1 at the line of the OV197 at Exist column. The number of OVs in RES1 lines can be of order of 2, 3 and more.
The order per sequenceID is an important issue. Only OV46 before OV197 is indicated as 1.

Comment: I think in the expected the last two `items` is not matching with the input

Comment: @Jaap this is completely different, That's the reason I opened a new question. Why points were removed?

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I highly appreciate all your help.

Comment: Also, SO recommends to ask new questions instead of asking 100 followup questions in a single out.  I would not have recommended to open a new question if it was like `how to change the column class to a character class` or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the last alphanumeric string from the 'sequence' column in 'RES1' using `stri_extract_last` from `library(stringi)`.  Use this to compare against the 'items' column in 'SRC2' and coerce the logical to binary by wrapping with `+`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(SRC2)`) before doing this.  Grouped by 'sequenceID', we get the `sum` of 'Exist', divide it by nrow (`.N`), `round`, convert to `character` class to create 'Co'.  Change the elements in 'Co' that are not the last one per each 'sequenceID' to `''` using the row index (`.I`).

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
v1 <- stri_extract_last_regex(RES1$sequence, '[[:alnum:]]+')
setDT(SRC2)[, Exist:= +(items %chin% v1)]
i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , 
         sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1
SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
SRC2
#   sequenceID transactionID eventID items Exist   Co
#1:   42207993          1577       1  OV50     1     
#2:   42207993          6048       2  OV11     0     
#3:   42207993          1597       3 OV148     1 0.67
#4:   57237976         12423       1  OV46     0     
#5:   57237976         12589       2 OV197     1  0.5
```

#### data

```
 SRC2 <- structure(list(sequenceID = c(42207993L, 42207993L, 42207993L, 
57237976L, 57237976L), transactionID = c(1577L, 6048L, 1597L, 
12423L, 12589L), eventID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), items = c("OV50", 
"OV11", "OV148", "OV46", "OV197")), .Names = c("sequenceID", 
"transactionID", "eventID", "items"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

 RES1 <- structure(list(sequence = c("<{OV50}>", "<{OV148}>", 
 "<{OV46},{OV197}>", 
"<{OV198},{OV199}, {OV205}>"), support = c(0.286, 0.121, 0.065, 
0.065)), .Names = c("sequence", "support"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: The answer is correct for the above given example, but in case of special characters in columns contents it won't necessarily work. Please find the following for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766280/using-special-characters-in-columns-values

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I'll be glad if you can look at my real example.

Comment: @Avi I will look into it.  Right now, I am a bit busy with work

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I'll be grateful!

Comment: @Avi Got bogged down with some huge access database formulas.