# Using special characters in columns values

Tags: r

I use the following code:

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
v1 <- stri_extract_last_regex(RES1$sequence, '[[:alnum:]]+')
setDT(SRC2)[, Exist:= +(items %chin% v1)]
i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , 
         sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1
SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
```

When RES1 contains the normal values for "sequence":

```
"sequence" "support"
    "1" "<{OV50}>"   0.286
    "2" "<{OV148}>"  0.121
    "3" "<{OV46},{OV197}>" 0.065
    "4" "<{OV198},{OV199}, {OV205}>" 0.065
```

And SRC2 contains normal values for "items":

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"
```

The output:

```
"sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1       0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"     0
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"    1       0.5
```

The code works perfectly. However the values of "sequence" and "items" hold many letters including special characters such as:

RES1:

```
                                         sequence    support
1         <{EADFE20F543836047330DEFFB893127AF536560121698ADE2FCE6985E07A40D8 SELECT;DD2E595CF23E65E128560B655E0C6848 SELECT}> 0.286
2                                                                                 <{F73431225ED64969DC4BEBD06092FD6F SELECT}> 0.121
3         <{9AD4E96D7EF2FC7B64407EAF4E2274868B2C0545BFBA9F15F828D9986D484A4D CALL}, {828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT}  > 0.065
4                                                 <{1C9AAE933F916BA94B5D2B5FA320E05D85C780CD1A9922E26BC1FB7C422F42B2 SELECT}{3FCC23C2562BE9926049EAF2D88CD3D4 SELECT;314CD91DCA8849C64DCEACBA2E3B65B7 SELECT;09E9146A444AE1C47B8E4139D6D69A48 SELECT},{184E7C8929FC9CEA72EF21D99CDC40D9 SELECT}, {184E7C8929EREREERE72EF21D99CDC40D9 SELECT}> 0.065
```

and SRC2:

```
   sequenceID   transactionID   eventID           items
1:   42207993    1577            1             EADFE20F543836047330DEFFB893127AF536560121698ADE2FCE6985E07A40D8 SELECT;DD2E595CF23E65E128560B655E0C6848 SELECT 
2:   42207993    6048            2             15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL
3:   42207993    1597            3             F73431225ED64969DC4BEBD06092FD6F SELECT
4:   57237976    12423           1             9AD4E96D7EF2FC7B64407EAF4E2274868B2C0545BFBA9F15F828D9986D484A4D CALL
5:   57237976    12589           2             828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT
```

The required output:

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "<{EADFE20F543836047330DEFFB893127AF536560121698ADE2FCE6985E07A40D8 SELECT;DD2E595CF23E65E128560B655E0C6848 SELECT}>"     1
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "{15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL}"     0
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "{F73431225ED64969DC4BEBD06092FD6F SELECT}"    1       0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "{9AD4E96D7EF2FC7B64407EAF4E2274868B2C0545BFBA9F15F828D9986D484A4D CALL}"     0
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "{828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT}"    1       0.5
```

What do I need to change in code so it will handle the special characters? (the code runs but the results are not as expected).

As can be seen there is one to one relation between the tables, only the "sequence" and "items" columns content has been changed. So there no need to change the logic only the way of handling the "sequence" and "items" columns content.

Comment: could go for a `dput` of your data

Comment: @MichaelChirico, please notice that it doesn't include all the contents and it is a bit different (only in values) from what I presented in my question.

Comment: Can you also show the expected output (for reference)

Comment: Sure. I'll do it in a moment.

Comment: Also, please update your post with the dput instead of in the comments as it will be easier to copy

Comment: I updated the required results (just replaced the nice OVx with the long strings. As for dput - I use very big data this is only an example. I can send you the data by email if you would like to.

Comment: I am at workplace, so not able to access emails

Comment: Maybe you can use the example in the question body. Just read it as a dataframe. Same as it was done with the ordinary OV values.

Comment: I have a doubt.  Are you comparing the last substring of `sequence` from `RES1` with the last of `SRC2$items` i.e. after the `;` delimiter

Comment: Practically the ; is only a sign it is considered as part of long string (same OV). You can relate to it as if it is any other character and I need to compare all characters of RES1$sequence  with all characters of SRC2$items.

Comment: I checked the RES1$sequence.  It seems to have multiple delimiters.  For example the third observation `"<{9AD4E96D7EF2FC7B64407EAF4E2274868B2C0545BFBA9F15F828D9986D484A4D CALL}, {828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT}  >"`

Comment: As I mentioned relate to it as an ordinary character to be compared.

Comment: the { } is a different OV. The , splits between the different OV (see in the simple example {OV46},{OV197}. However ;  is an inner character in the OV.

Comment: What about `{OV46}{OV197}` as it is the 4th row

Comment: Each of them has its own very long strings with {}. See row 3 in RES1 before and after. The only thing was to replace the OV with long strings that inside the string might be ; as a character the rest is the same.

Comment: Try this `v1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(RES1$sequence, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1)))';
v2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(SRC2$items, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1))); +(v2 %in% v1)` and do as previously.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will take me a bit more than an hour to check it. However, did you notice that inside the strings in addition to ; there are spaces as well?

Comment: Hi @akrun, I added the head of the real files at the end of the question body. And got the the following error for v1: > v1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(RES1$sequence, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1)))'; v2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(SRC2$items, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1))); +(v2 %in% v1)
Error: unexpected string constant in "v1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(RES1$sequence, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1)))'; v2 <- trimws(gsub('"

Comment: There was ' between v1 and v2 and I erased it and still: v1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(RES1$sequence, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[\\,\\;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1))); 
v2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', sapply(strsplit(SRC2$items, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', perl=TRUE), tail, 1))); +(v2 %in% v1)
I got: Error in strsplit(RES1$sequence, "(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]", perl = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument

Comment: @Avi Looks like the first error you got solved from posting a new question.  The second error is because the column is `factor`.  Convert to `character` class `strsplit(as.character(SRC2$items),...`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I edited the code (I added it at the end of the question) but I still don't get the correct required results.

Comment: Based on the data you showed, I was getting the `1 0 1 0 1` for Exist.  That is the reason I posted the comment earlier.

Comment: Is there a way to send you my files?

Comment: @akrun, please find at the end of the question the corrected code I use. I get only 0 for both Exist and CO columns. What is wrong with what I do?

Comment: @Avi Let me try to copy/paste the examples again and check

Comment: My code was working on the earlier SRC2 and RES1.  Looks like you have another updated SRC2 and RES1.  Which one is closely matching with the original dataset

Comment: The example I sent is a synthesis of the real files (I just extracted rows to show what I mean). The head of the RES1 and SRC2 are the real headers but I'm not sure they contain required data to get required results. If there a way I can send you my file I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Avi The problem with me is that all emails are blocked at worksite.  Also, I can't access dropbox here.

Comment: Is there a way to send you and you will look at it after work? Can you explain me how did you insert the data into the SRC2 and RES1?

Comment: @Avi Can you send it to akrun111@gmail.com  (I guess this is the one I created just for stackoverflow).  I will check it later.

Comment: @akrun, please add your answer, I would like you to get the credit for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
v1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', 
   sapply(strsplit(RES1$sequence, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', 
             perl=TRUE), tail, 1)))
v2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '',
     sapply(strsplit(SRC2$items, '(?<=\\})(?=\\{)|[[,;]', 
           perl=TRUE), tail, 1)))
setDT(SRC2)[, Exist:= +(v2 %chin% v1)]
i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , 
        sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1
SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
```